# Prevent repainting when using css sprite animations

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-animations

Is it possible at all to prevent the repaint taking place when running a css sprite animation?

[image]

I tried using `will-change: background-position;` And it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all in this regard.

[Demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/4xafot6p/5/)

(Try this link without iframe if you want to see the repainting)
https://fiddle.jshell.net/alvarotrigo/4xafot6p/5/show/

```
.demo{
    position: absolute;
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2600/1*WhDjw8GiV5o0flBXM4LXEw.png');
    background-position: 0 0;

}
.demo.active{
    bottom: -20px;

    will-change: background;
    animation: play_1 300ms steps(6) infinite;
}
@keyframes play_1 {
   from{ background-position-x: 0; }
   to{ background-position-x: -1536px; }
}
```

Comment: its work fine on my browser

Comment: Jsfiddle keeps it inside an iframe. That might be the cause of Chrome dev tolls not dealing with the rendering debug properly.
Try from here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/alvarotrigo/4xafot6p/5/show/

Comment: still work fine :)

Comment: You are changing the background position, repainting should be done, right? I believe only that element will be repainting, which looks fine to me. Is there any reason why you don't want it to happen? (Apart from the obvious ones).

Comment: @Prajwal it doesn't 't have to be the case. See my fix using a pseudo element here: https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/4xafot6p/6/ 
Element won't get repainted there. Which makes it smoother for the browser.

Comment: @Nori is not about working or not working.It is about repainting vs non repainting.

Comment: I should check out your solution tomorrow. BTW, why do you think adding will-change would reduce repainting?

Comment: Apparently it creates a new layer and prevents repainting. [Here's an article from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas). I've tested it in another scenarios and it seems to do the work.